# PL/SQL and date intervals

Tags: oracle, plsql, intervals

I have a date and I'd like to print the offset from that date. I can do this:

```
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(g_startDate - interval '4' month ,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

and it works fine. The problem is that the interval is variable. When I try this:

```
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(g_startDate - interval g_dateOffsetAmt month ,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I get a compiler error.

I thought it might be because `g_dateOffsetAmt` is an `integer` so I tried this:

```
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(g_startDate - interval to_char(g_dateOffsetAmt) month ,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Though I still get compiler errors saying:

```
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TO_CHAR" when expecting one of the following:

          . ) , * @ & | = - +  at in is mod remainder not rem =>
          ..   or != or ~= >=  and or like
          LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ as between from using || member
           SUBMULTISET_
       The symbol "," was substituted for "TO_CHAR" to continue.
Line: 704

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MONTH" when expecting one of the following:

          . ( ) , * % & | = - +  at in is mod remainder not range
          rem => ..   or != or ~= >=  and or
          like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset member
          SUBMULTISET_
       The symbol "." was substituted for "MONTH" to continue.
Line: 704
```

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this..  Either type your variable being passed in as an interval, or use the function add_months instead:

```
declare
    v_interval INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH := interval '4' month;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char((sysdate - v_interval), 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
end; 

declare
    v_interval PLS_INTEGER := 4;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(add_months(sysdate, -v_interval), 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
end;
```

Comment: Yup, `add_months` does exactly what I want. And to think I've used it before and just forgot about it :( Man I really need the weekend!

Comment: And using add months gets around the annoying problem of ORA-01839 when using interval arithmetic at the end of a month, e.g. `date '2010-03-30' - interval '1' month`. But then add_months has its own problems at the end of the month too, if you compare `add_months(date '2010-02-27',1)` and `add_months(date '2010-02-28',1)`

Answer (score 6):

You would probably want to use the NumToYMInterval function

```
declare
  v_interval pls_integer := 4;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line( sysdate - NumToYMInterval( v_interval, 'month' ) );
end;
/
```

Comment: I'll have to try to remember this one as well.